# Add and remove action bar depending on fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-actionbar

I am making an app with four fragments but i want the action bar to only show on two fragments. I tried using:

```
getActivity.getActionBar().hide();
```

But that only makes the fragment crash. Please any ideas what to do? Thankyou

Comment: Have you tried with `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`? Please also add the exception you're getting, that will let others have a better idea of your problem. Regards!

Comment: Yeah i did but when i used the getSupportActionBar() method it appeared in red

Answer (score 0):

Try this..Its works for me

To Hide `ActionBar`

```
     ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

To Show `ActionBar`

```
     ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
```

Comment: @user999991 check my answer

Comment: Yeah i did. the getSupportActionBarMethod() appeared in  red.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....,

Hide Actionbar,

```
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Show Actionbar,

```
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

If your using AppCompatActivity then you should add the following code to your onCreate() before setContentView in the fragment.

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

to show actionbar

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
```

The support fragment's getActivity() returns a FragmentActivity, and its doesn't contain the getSupportActionBar() method. Using just getActionBar() gives null-pointer exception if you use AppCompatActivity, then you need to use `getActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide();` and `getActivity().getActionBar().show();` accordingly.